# $\frac{y-b}{r}=\frac{y}{s}$ to $y$ for finding the closest point on a line, from a point.

Tags: geometry, polynomials

$$r=sy^2-sby$$

How do I get $y$ on one side?

Originally I had:

$\dfrac{y-b}{r}=\dfrac{y}{s}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice, we have $$\frac{y-b}{r}=\frac{y}{s}$$ $$\frac{y-b}{y}=\frac{r}{s}$$ $$\frac{y-b}{y}-1=\frac{r}{s}-1$$ $$\frac{y-b-y}{y}=\frac{r-s}{s}$$ $$\frac{-b}{y}=\frac{r-s}{s}$$ $$\frac{-y}{b}=\frac{s}{r-s}$$ $$y=\frac{-bs}{r-s}$$ $$y=\frac{sb}{s-r}$$

Answer (score 1):

$\frac{(y−b)}{r}=\frac{y}{s} \Rightarrow s(y-b)=ry \Rightarrow sy-sb=ry \Rightarrow sy-ry=sb \Rightarrow y(s-r)=sb \Rightarrow y=\frac{sb}{(s-r)}.$